# How to send mail by selecting the dropdown details?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the dropdown list with fields Lab,Pharmacy,Food and Nurse.When I select the lab it generates the new fields and when I select the pharmacy it generates the new field with upload button.I need to send the mail with these details for lab and pharmacy.

By using below mail function I can send only for lab but when I select pharmacy I could not send any mail.Please help me

Form.phtml

```
  <form action="http://www.labwise.in/devel/serviceform/submit" id="quickservice" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li>
        <label for="Servicetype" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select id='servicetype'   onchange="showHidden(this)" name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 200px;" />
                        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                        <option value="Lab" id='lab'><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                        <option value="Pharmacy"><?php echo $this->__('Pharmacy')?></option>
                        <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                        <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                        <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                        <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fileToUpload" style='display: none;'>
       <div id="fileToUpload" style='display: none;'>

        <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="medicinename" ><?php echo $this->__('Medicine Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="medicinename" name="medicinename" value="" class="input-text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Medicine Name') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
    </div>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
    </div>
    <div id="city_name" style='display: none;'>
        <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="testname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Testname') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Testname') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
                <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="rcity" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="rcity" name="rcity" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

if(Validation) {
    Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
    function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

    var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
    // var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
    if(v.length > 0){
    if(v.length !=10){
        return false;
       }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

        return false;
       }


    return true;

    }else {
    return false;
    }

    }
    ]])};

var contactForm = new VarienForm('quickservice', true);
 //]]>
 </script>

  <script>
    function showHidden(elem){
       if(elem.value == 'Pharmacy')
       {
          document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(elem.value == 'Lab')
       {
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
       }
       else
       {
          document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
       }
    }
 </script>
```

Mail.phtml

```
   <?php
    //Admin Mail
 function sendMailAction(){
//Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
 $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $testname=$_POST['testname'];
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
 $city=$_POST['rcity'];


 $html=
 ' <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
<p>Testname:'.$testname.' </p>
<p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
<p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
<p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
<p>City: '.$city.'</p>'


    ;
         $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
         $mail->setToName('admin');
   $mail->setToEmail($email);
   $mail->setBody($html);
   $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
   $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
   $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
  //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
   $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

    try {
     $mail->send();
     //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
     //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
      //return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
        //$this->_redirect('');
         }
        catch (Exception $e) {
       //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
        //$this->_redirect('');
             }
             }
          //Customer Mail

             function sendMailcustomerAction(){
             //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
              $email=$_POST['email'];
               $testname=$_POST['testname'];
               $name=$_POST['name'];
               $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
                $city=$POST_['city'];

                 $html=
                'Dear '.$name.',

                   <p>We have received your order for '.$testname.'. You will be attended shortly.</p>

                  <p>Best Regards,</p>
                   <p>Team Labwise.</p>'

           ;
            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
            $mail->setToName($name);
            $mail->setToEmail($email);
               $mail->setBody($html);
            $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
             $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
            $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
            //$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
            $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

       try {
        $mail->send();
           //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
           //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
             return '<h2>Your Request has been submitted.Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
            //$this->_redirect('');
            }
           catch (Exception $e) {
          //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
        //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
         return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';
        //$this->_redirect('');
           }
            }

 //pharmacy

   $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
   $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
    $query="SELECT *
     FROM mg_serviceprovider  where islab='1' or ispharmacy='1'";
   $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($query);

     foreach($alldata as $data)
       {
         if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy') { 
             sendMailpharmacyandlabAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
      } else {
      sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
      }
      }
     function sendMailpharmacyandlabAction($cemail,$pname){
     //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
     $cemail=$_POST['email'];

       if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $servicetype=='Pharmacy')
      {

        $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
        $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

        $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
        $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
        if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
            @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
        }
    }

     $html=
     '<p>Hi,</p>'

   ;

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
 $mail->setToName($pname);
$mail->setToEmail($cemail);
$mail->setBody($html);
$mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
$mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
$mail->setFromName("Labwise");
  if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
    {
      $mail->createAttachment(
              file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename),
            Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
            Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            basename($uploadfilename)
        );
    }
 //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
 $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

 try {
$mail->send();


 unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename); 
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
  //$this->_redirect('');
  }
catch (Exception $e) {
 //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
//$this->_redirect('');
 }
 }
echo sendMailpharmacyandlabAction();
echo sendMailserviceAction();
 echo sendMailcustomerAction();
 echo sendMailAction();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in you function for file attachment.

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
   $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
   $query="SELECT *
  FROM mg_serviceprovider  where islab='1' or ispharmacy='1'";
  $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($query);

     foreach($alldata as $data)
     {
         if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy') { 
sendMailpharmacyandlabAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
 } else {
          sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
         }
     }
```

email function for pharmacy

```
function sendMailpharmacyandlabAction($email,$pname){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
 $cemail=$_POST['email'];
 $bloodgroup=$_POST['bloodgroup'];
 $unitsrequired=$_POST['unitsrequired'];
 $requireddate=$_POST['requiredby'];
 $rcity=$_POST['rcity'];
 $city=$_POST['city'];
if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
        {

            $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
            $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

            $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
            $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
            if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
                @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
            }
        }

 $hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
 //$location=$_POST['location'];

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
 $yourbloodgroup=$_POST['yourbloodgroup'];

 $html=
'Hi,
<p>
<p><h2>Requisition Details:</h2> </p>
<p>Bloodgroup: '.$bloodgroup.'</p>
 <p>Units Required:'.$unitsrequired.'</p>
 <p>Required By:'. $requireddate.'</p>
 <p>City: '.$rcity.'</p>
 <p>Hospital:'.$hospital.'</p>

 <p><h2>Seeker Details:</h2></p>

 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
 <p>YourBloodgroup:'.$yourbloodgroup.'</p>'

;

 $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
  $mail->setToName($pname);
 $mail->setToEmail($email);
 $mail->setBody($html);
 $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
 $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
 $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
        {
        $mail->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);

        }
 //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
 $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
  $mail->send();


unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename); 
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
  //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
//return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
  //$this->_redirect('');
  }
 catch (Exception $e) {
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
 // return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
 //$this->_redirect('');
 }
 }
```

Comment: Ok.But I need to send this file only when I select pharmacy.But it is going for lab providers also

Comment: added the condition for that..

Comment: unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename); add this code for removing the uploaded file.

Comment: whare I need to add the code for removing the uploaded file

Comment: after $mail->send(); that

Comment: But it is not sending the mail for pharmacy.It is ending the lab details only

Comment: Can we create a separate functions for selecting lab and pharamacy and for other fields and when we select lab and click submit it should send the lab details and when we select pharmacy it should send the pharmacy details to providers and customers and for our admin

Comment: yes you can create that send the separate mail for them.

Comment: Ok can you please change my mail code according to that.By selecting the lab from dropdown list it has to send the mail with lab details.When I select the pharmacy it has to send the mail with pharmacy details.

Comment: add the function. in updated answer

Comment: Which function?

Comment: i anded the separate function as you asked

Comment: Ok.This code sends the email only when I select the pharmacy

Comment: it will send the product attachment it's up to you where you want to set it.

Comment: But in the body we have a lab details and it is showing unable to submit for pharmacy

Comment: change function for pharmacy..   `if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy') { //call function here }`

Comment: we need to add for each and every function for sending the details for pharmacy in my mail code.

Comment: if the used select the pharmacy then you want to send data only to pharmacy?

Comment: we have a different fields for lab and pharmacy.We need to send mails with different bodies for lab and pharmacy

Comment: change the body in last  answer i provide you and set it only for pharmacy..

Comment: Ok.But the code is going to big and getting confusion.Can you please reduce and make it fine

Comment: the code will go bigger time to time when you add more functionalities. you can pass common values from function to reduce the size

Comment: Ok.Can you please provide a total answer for lab and pharmacy according to the my form fields.

Comment: done with that updated answer

Comment: should I add below my code.Can you please suggest where I need to add this code in my mail.phtml

Comment: It is not working.It is showing unable to submit

Comment: change the code kindly check and feedback me..

Comment: It is not showing any confirmation message

Comment: I have added your code in my mail.phtml file.Please check it and test from your side also and suggest me if there are any issues.It is not working from my side.]

Comment: Check where is error. And also in media requestquote folder is created

Comment: no requestcode folder is not created

Comment: then create it. and check file is uploading or not.

Comment: yes created and tested but the folder is empty

Comment: updated the answer problem with the if condition..

Comment: It is showing same empty page after submission

Comment: check the error log for the error..

Comment: I have checked the system.log file but there is no error

Comment: Please help me it is not working.It is very important for me.

Comment: try to comment attachment code and see mail is working.

Comment: without attachement it is working fine

Comment: check the file is upload or not?

Comment: where I need to check the file is uploaded or not?

Comment: heloo please give me reply

Comment: media/requestquote/yourfile

Comment: yes the file is uploaded

Comment: update the answer try that and feedback

Comment: No.It is not working the image is also not uploading in the requestquote folder